# Django - Given the display of a model choice, how to retrieve the value from the Choice tuple?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have the model field with the following choice set:

```
TYPES = (
    ('1', 'Option1'),
    ('2', 'Option2'),
    ('3', 'Option3'),
```

and I have the string 'Option3', how can I obtain the value 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most places, Django will handle this for you. E.g. in the admin, the dropdown will display `'Option3'`, and the admin view will write the appropriate value `'3'` to the db. Otherwise you can use straight-forward Python. [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) comprehension seems simplest:

```
value = {v: k for k, v in TYPES}['Option3']
```

Comment: Simple and beautiful. Thank you!